# Finding file name in files section of current Ansible role

Tags: ansible

I'm fairly new to Ansible and I'm trying to create a role that copies a file to a remote server. The local file can have a different name every time I'm running the playbook, but it needs to be copied to the same name remotely, something like this:

```
- name: copy file
  copy:
    src=*.txt
    dest=/path/to/fixedname.txt
```

Ansible doesn't allow wildcards, so when I wrote a simple playbook with the tasks in the main playbook I could do:

```
- name: find the filename
    connection: local
    shell: "ls -1 files/*.txt"
    register: myfile

- name: copy file
  copy:
    src="files/{{ item }}"
    dest=/path/to/fixedname.txt
  with_items:
   - myfile.stdout_lines
```

However, when I moved the tasks to a role, the first action didn't work anymore, because the relative path is relative to the role while the playbook executes in the root dir of the 'roles' directory. I could add the path to the role's files dir, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: It's odd that this would work - the shell module runs remotely, but from your explanation you're finding a local filename?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add 'connection: local', I'll update the text.

Comment: Would `synchronize` module do what you need? http://docs.ansible.com/synchronize_module.html

Comment: @mxx Good point, the synchronize module would also be a solution.

Comment: @Mxx I've tried 'synchronize' and I've run into 2 issues: I needed to install 'rsync' on the remote site and the second is still my initial problem: the relative path is started from the root of the play-book, not the root of the role.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you need access to a task that looks up information locally, and then uses that information as input to the copy module.

There are two ways to get local information.

- use `local_action:`. That's shorthand for running the task agains 127.0.0.1, more info found [here](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html). (this is what you've been using)
- use a `lookup`. This is a plugin system specifically designed for getting information locally. More info [here](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html).

In your case, I would go for the second method, using `lookup`. You could set it up like this [example](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups):

```
vars:
  local_file_name: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ls -1 files/*.txt') }}"

tasks:
  - name: copy file
    copy: src="{{ local_file_name }}" dest=/path/to/fixedname.txt
```

Or, more directly:

```
tasks:
  - name: copy file
    copy: src="{{ lookup('pipe', 'ls -1 files/*.txt') }}" dest=/path/to/fixedname.txt
```

### With regards to paths

the lookup plugin is run from the context of the task (playbook vs role). This means that it will behave differently depending on where it's used.

In the setup above, the tasks are run directly from a playbook, so the working dir will be:

`/path/to/project` -- this is the folder where your playbook is.

If you where to add the task to a role, the working dir would be:

`/path/to/project/roles/role_name/tasks`

In addition, the `file` and `pipe` plugins run from within the *role/files* folder **if it exists**:

`/path/to/project/roles/role_name/files` -- this means your command is `ls -1 *.txt`

#### caveat:

The plugin is called every time you access the variable. This means you cannot trust debugging the variable in your playbook, and then relying on the variable to have the same value when used later in a role!

I do wonder though, about the use-case for a file that resides inside a projects ansible folders, but who's name is not known in advance. Where does such a file come from? Isn't it possible to add a layer in between the generation of the file and using it in Ansible... or having a fixed local path as a variable? Just curious ;)

Comment: This sounds like a good suggestion, so I'm going to try it out as soon as possible. Re source of the file: it's a build from Jenkins that contains a version in the name. Right now I have no idea how to get that build downloaded automatically, so I want to do that by hand and place the files in the appropriate dir.

Comment: You download a build file from somewhere manually and then add it to your machine in an ansible role? That seems like the wrong way to look at automation :-)  --- how about you add a play *before* your current play, to connecnt and download the file from your Jenkins machine?

Comment: A fully automated play is the ultimate goal :-) But I haven't figured out yet how to get past the login form of Jenkins, so rather than getting stuck on the first step in the playbook, I'm focusing on writing the rest of the playbook and download the Jenkins files manually. After that the Ansible playbook can be tested, while I focus on the automated download from Jenkins problem.

Comment: I've tested the lookup statement in a debug message, but it looks like either I'm missing some parameter or your assumption is wrong. When the lookup statement is run from a playbook role, it still takes the 'root' directory of the playbook as working directory, not the directory of the role. I'm using Ansible 1.5.5.

Comment: You know what.. I wrote it down specifically because that surprised me too. It wasn't an assumption I wrote a test playbook, I'll post that in my answer in a minute. I do get different results though, using Ansbile 1.5.5 a variable *does* retain it's value, but in 1.6.1 it does not. Seems like something to raise on the mailing list. -- so remember: you **could** be in for trouble when you upgrade.

Comment: aha, apart from the version I couldn't get it to work as variable, so I added it as a debug task. So there might be differences in behaviour too.

Comment: This is my repo on github: https://github.com/ramondelafuente/ansible-lookup-plugin-tests. It checks for the variable + debugs the plugin directly. You should be able to check that out and run it with `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml`

Comment: I ran your playbook with no errors and it looks like there is a path difference, however see https://github.com/hepabolu/ansible-lookup-plugin-tests where I've added my task, which throws an error with Ansible 1.5.5.

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to throw in an additional answer... I have the same problem as you, where I build an ansible bundle on the fly and copy artifacts (rpms) into a role's files folder, and my rpms have versions in the filename.

When I run the ansible play, I want it to install all rpms, regardless of filenames.

I solved this by using the `with_fileglob` mechanism in ansible:

```
- name: Copy RPMs
  copy: src="{{ item }}" dest="{{ rpm_cache }}"
  with_fileglob: "*.rpm"
  register: rpm_files

- name: Install RPMs
  yum: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items: "{{ rpm_files.results | map(attribute='dest') | list }}"
```

I find it a little bit cleaner than the lookup mechanism.

Comment: Keep in mind that all lookup plugins (and fileglob is one of them) do searches on localhost (ansible host). So this example will work correctly only if both of your tasks are executed on localhost, otherwise second task will search for `/tmp/*.rmp` on localhost and try to yum install this local files on remote host.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I replaced the 2nd with_fileglob with a shell + ls command.

Comment: I'd opt for registering result of copy and use it's items to loop the yum module.

Comment: Neat! I just switched to a copy with fileglob, register the results, then iterate over the dest field of results with the yum module. Super clean, thanks!